# Abort ajax file uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I need to implement AJAX file uploading interruption by click on cancel button. 
Here's code which I'm trying to use:

```
var reqx=null;

function ajax_upload(){
    reqx = $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "/file.php",
        data: new FormData( $('#file')[0] ),
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    })
}

$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
    ajax_upload();
});

$('#cancel').click(function(){
    if (reqx != null){ 
        reqx.abort();
        reqx = null;
    }
});
```

Clicking on Cancel button causes an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: reqx.abort is not a function
```

Need help to find out mistake in my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC your looking for resolve().  http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/  It causes the deferred to immediately complete and process any done logic.

Comment: `abort()` is a legit method, see : [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

Comment: From the top comment: [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#abort%28%29)

Comment: Ah, ok.  And I found where the docs say the jqXHR for backwards compatability do expose the abort method.  So yeah, not sure why it's giving that error.